# What is selling intensity, loss intensity, and how can I calibrate them?

Tags: econometrics, liquidity, stress-testing

Thought asking around on a problem I'm currently facing.
I have a hypothetical multi-asset portfolio of equities and bonds, on which I'm trying to measure it's liquidity risk in stressed periods. I've read Roncalli's four-piece paper on Liquidity Stress Testing in the Asset Management Industry ([link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3981920)), and in it they suggest using a cash conversion factor for a sixty day period, to determine the price impact on the asset over that period. It is as follows:

Cash Conversion Factor(time) = Liquidity Factor x (1 - Discount Factor), where Liquidity Factor = Min(1, selling intensity x time); Discount Factor = Min(Maximum Drawdown, Loss Intensity x square root(time)).

In it, they suggest a selling intensity of 5% and a loss intensity of 6.25%, which would result in the following
[image]

However, I'm unclear on what they mean about selling and loss intensities, much less how it is derived, and how can it be calibrated, for bonds and equities.
Can anyone assist?
And apologies if it sounds too simplistic, I only have a basic understanding of econometrics and statistics!

Comment: Do thesse old questions help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14609 , https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35141